# Why aren't my pictures placed to the right side of the text?

Tags: html, css

Hi would you know why my pictures are placed under my text articles and not on the right side as I would like? Many thanks http://jsfiddle.net/2RqGu/1/

**Pictures placed under the next instead of right-side of the text:**
[image]
HTML

```
<div class="block width100 white-background">
    <ol class="block_numbers">
         <h3>Notre approche</h3>

        <li>
            <p><strong>Title 1</strong>

            </p>
            <div class="element">
                <article>
                    <p>eugiat neque. Vivamus placerat, mi sed vulputate euismod, enim justo pellentesque justo, sit amet aliquet tortor est ac turpis. Pellentesque consequat libero non fringilla dictum. Proin risus lectus, imperdiet tincidunt massa quis, consequat porttitor dui. Nam vel mi sed enim sollicitudin varius ut ac augue.</p>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
                </article>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p><strong>Title 2</strong>

            </p>
            <div class="element">
                <article>
                    <p>eugiat neque. Vivamus placerat, mi sed vulputate euismod, enim justo pellentesque justo, sit amet aliquet tortor est ac turpis. Pellentesque consequat libero non fringilla dictum. Proin risus lectus, imperdiet tincidunt massa quis, consequat porttitor dui. Nam vel mi sed enim sollicitudin varius ut ac augue.</p>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
                </article>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block {
    padding: 20px;
    background-clip: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
.width100 {
    width: 100%;
}
.white-background {
    background: #fff;
}
.block_numbers {
    counter-reset: li;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.block_numbers h3 {
    color: #3A7CDB;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.block_numbers p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}
.block_numbers > li {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 0 27px;
    position: relative;
}
.block_numbers > li:before {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3A7CDB;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    content: counter(li, decimal);
    counter-increment: li;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding: 1px 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: -2px;
    width: 22px;
}
.element {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    background:rgb(134, 226, 255);
    margin:10px 0px;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
p {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
    background:white;
}
img {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an image as to be placed in a `<p>` to produce valid HTML. If you want to keep the image outside the white background, then create a second paragraph.

```
        <article>
            <p class="content">eugiat neque. Vivamus placerat, mi sed vulputate euismod, enim justo pellentesque justo, sit amet aliquet tortor est ac turpis. Pellentesque consequat libero non fringilla dictum. Proin risus lectus, imperdiet tincidunt massa quis, consequat porttitor dui. Nam vel mi sed enim sollicitudin varius ut ac augue.</p>
            <p class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></p>
        </article>
```

Second, you need to reduce the size of the first paragraph to keep place for the image:

```
  p.content {
      width:70%;
  }
```

**[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2RqGu/8/)**

Comment: Thanks Maxime. With your solution is it possible to have several paragraphs (several blocks of <p></p>) in case of long text while keeping the picture aligned to the top of the first paragraph? I tried here http://jsfiddle.net/2RqGu/13/ but the picture gets alignes to the top of the second paragraph, which looks odd. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Greg The best way is to get rid of the `display:table-cell`, put the image with `float:right` and write the `<p class="image">` as the first paragraph: http://jsfiddle.net/2RqGu/14/

Comment: @MaximeLorant, what is about the image width ? Can't it be more than 30% ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed It's a bit harder to make the width of the paragraph adapt to the image size. Here, the image can be adapt to fit 30%, or if it's a fixed design, he'll put width in px.

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot Maxime

Answer (score 1):

Added the width :

```
p {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
    background:white;

   width:70%;
}
```

`HTML p` is a block level element. SO if you do not give it  a width, it will have a width equal to  100%.

**EDIT:**
If  your images do not have any fixed width , then you can set a width for `img`:

```
img{

width:28%;
}
```

70% for `p`, 28% fro `img` . rest 2% for `margin` with `p` ( `.block_numbers p` ) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the main div that contains the rest, so that `width: 70%` has a reference.

Comment: you want the `element` class to have a 100% width ? Why on earth is that necessary ? A block level element will have a 100% width by default.

Answer (score 1):

Greg and maxime both are right just add some code blocks in your css and you're done just have a look at it some changes in the last section of css file http://jsfiddle.net/2RqGu/6/

```
p {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
    background:white;
    float:left;
    width:70%;
}
img {
    display:table-cell;
    float:right;
    width:30%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply set the width of paragraph's to '70%'

```
 p{ 
  width:70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't set any width % or px it occupies the whole block and pushes the image down.

here is the code that works

I have added a class to

TAG called "lt" which forces the Paragraph in article to give a room to the picture by setting its width to 73% .

```
<div class="block width100 white-background">
<ol class="block_numbers">
     <h3>Notre approche</h3>

    <li>
        <p><strong>Title 1</strong>

        </p>
        <div class="element">
            <article>
                **<p class="lt">**eugiat neque. Vivamus placerat, mi sed vulputate euismod, enim justo pellentesque justo, sit amet aliquet tortor est ac turpis. Pellentesque consequat libero non fringilla dictum. Proin risus lectus, imperdiet tincidunt massa quis, consequat porttitor dui. Nam vel mi sed enim sollicitudin varius ut ac augue.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            </article>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p><strong>Title 2</strong>

        </p>
        <div class="element">
            <article>
                **<p class="lt">**eugiat neque. Vivamus placerat, mi sed vulputate euismod, enim justo pellentesque justo, sit amet aliquet tortor est ac turpis. Pellentesque consequat libero non fringilla dictum. Proin risus lectus, imperdiet tincidunt massa quis, consequat porttitor dui. Nam vel mi sed enim sollicitudin varius ut ac augue.</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            </article>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

**lt** Class css code is

```
.lt{
  float:left;
  width:73%;
  position:relative;
}

img {
  display:table-cell;
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  width:25%;
}
```

[Working Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2RqGu/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `float` property.

```
 img {
     display:table-cell;
     float:right;
 }
```

Here is the update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2RqGu/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `Float` property :

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/qRMWf/)

**CSS**:

```
img {
    display:table-cell;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U need small changes in your css

```
p{

 width:60%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img
{
float:right;
}
```

It will work

Comment: why to float `img` right side ? why to use `overflow:hidden;` for `p` ?

Comment: @Ahmed I are giving the width as 60% so if content in p is more then overflow scroll bar will come so to prevent that overflow is hidden and for image just aligning to right side.

Comment: `overflow-x` will not happen, nor will `overflow-y` as `p` has a 100% width  and the wrapper `element` class does not have any fixed height. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution without `table-cell` or some predefined `width`, is putting the `img` in front of the paragraph

```html
<article>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    <p>eugiat neque. Vivamus placerat, mi sed vulputate ...</p>
</article>
```

remove `display: table*` and use

```css
.element img {
    float: right;
}
```

You must also be more specific for the title paragraph

```html
<p class="block_title"><strong>Title 1</strong>
```

and

```css
.block_numbers .block_title {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

otherwise this applies to the `.element` paragraphs as well.

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2RqGu/17/)